# "make" errors when installing Insight debugger on OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, installation, make

I'm trying to install the Insight debugger on OS X. I can execute `./configure` with no problem but when I try and run `make` it gets about half-way with no errors, but then starts spewing out errors(?) like:

```
../.././tcl/unix/../generic/regcomp.c:455: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘Tcl_Alloc’ with different width due to prototype`
```

Most of these end with `with different width due to prototype`

The fatal errors at the end are:

```
ld: library not found for -lX11
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [wish] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-tk] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have X11 installed as well as tk and wish. I've tried modifying the paths but the fatal errors still happen. Any ideas?

Comment: X11 != X11 development files

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate IV-A's comment a bit, most 'library not found' errors come about because you don't have the 'dev' files for the application installed.  It's not enough to have the working application itself, missing libraries usually point to the omission of the development libraries for the package, in this instance X11-dev.